# How to select a nested structure while preserving the nested structure in spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark

My data look like

```
key
    my_id1
    my_id2
value
    my_value1
    my_value2
```

I am only interested in  `my_value2` and `my_id2` `my_id1` but i want to preserve the nested structure

if i do

```
val myDf = myoriginalDF
  .select("key.*", "value.my_value2")
```

it returns

```
my_id1
my_id2
my_value2
```

how do i preserve the nested structure during select?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `select` with `struct` as below:

```scala
df.select(
    struct($"key.my_id1", $"key.my_id2").alias("key"),
    struct($"value.my_value2").alias("value")
  )
```

The schema of your output will be:

```
root
 |-- key: struct 
 |    |-- my_id1
 |    |-- my_id2
 |-- value: struct
 |    |-- my_value2
```

Which should be what you want, good luck!